# apache-solr apache-tika indexing documents. Slow speed

Tags: apache, solr, amazon-ec2, apache-tika

I have 4GB ram.
running solr on 3GB memory.

I am extracting text and meta data using apache-tika server (tika-server.jar).

Files are taking much longer time than usual. 20 MB file is taking 2 - 3 minutes.

My server is hosted on amazon cloud. running ubuntu 14.04.

I have tested this on my local machine it extracts the data from same file in 1-2 secs.

is there a special configuration needed for amazon cloud instance. My local machine also has 4GB ram but its a MAC OS.

I am using tika-python to index my documents.

I have around 1 million documents in different file formats (pdf,htlm,doc,ppt,xml,txt)

Please suggest a remedy or an alternative solution to Apache-Tika.

THanks

---

My system has ubuntu without libre office installed in it.

Slow indexing is happening for .doc files only.

Is there any alternative solution to parse full text and meta data from MS Office files (doc, docx, etc). Which would give a better speed.

Comment: Is it the Tika step taking the time, or the SOLR step?

Comment: Are you using Solr's document extraction or using a stand alone tika server? Can you compare the log files on your local machine and amazon cloud server? Everytime you try to use tika on Amazon cloud, you have to upload the 20 mb file to the server, and then the extraction works. So probably the 2-3 minutes is just the upload time + extraction + sending back response (which I am assuming will be quite large for a 20 mb file)?

Comment: Hi, Gagravarr Tika is taking time. not solr indexing.  jay i m using standalone tika, not the inbuilt in solr. Files are stored in my amazon cloud I have already uploaded them to amazon drive. thangs.

Comment: My Amazon Cloud instance is c4.large Ubuntu (2 vCPU, 3.75 GB ram) , and My MAC is 1.2 GHZ with 4gb ram. SHould I go for a different hosting plan.

Comment: @jay  Please help me out. My Ubuntu machine does not have libre office also. while my mac has MS Office installed. what should I do , I need to spped up by indexing process. My Tika parser is taking a lot of time for .doc files only. same size files in pdf are being parsed much faster.